# (git bash) push to bitbucket ignores SSH key

Tags: windows, git, ssh, bitbucket, git-bash

I followed a bunch of blog trails around the web to find out how everything should be set up and I have the following situation:

First of all, `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` returns the following result

```
conq: logged in as myuser.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
```

That means I have the ssh key setup properly both local and in bitbucket, agreed?

I have a *~/.ssh/config* with the following content:

```
Host bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

That key is there ofcourse.

However, when I try the command (taken from another tutorial) `git push origin master`, I will get a popup saying:

```
---------------------------
PuTTY Fatal Error
---------------------------
Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
---------------------------
OK
```

---

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Judging by the error `PuTTY Fatal Error`, it looks like Git is trying to use PuTTY to authenticate with ssh. The thing is PuTTY is not aware of your setting in `~/.ssh`, at all. The setting in `~/.ssh` is only meaningful when using `openssh`, shipped with Git Bash. It looks as if you have set the `GIT_SSH` environment variable to `plink.exe`, which is a tool that's part PuTTY.

You have two choices: you can either use PuTTY and `plink.exe` for ssh operations, or you can use the `openssh` that is part of Git Bash.

If you use PuTTY, then you need to manage your ssh keys with `pageant.exe`, which is also part of PuTTY. It's a pretty nice tool. Run it, and in the task tray you should see an icon. Right-click on that icon to add your private key. The other step to use PuTTY is setting `GIT_SSH` but it looks like you've already done that. In this setup `git push` will use `plink.exe`, which being part of PuTTY, will correctly find the private keys stored by `pageant.ext`.

If you want to use the `openssh` that is part of Git Bash, then all you need to do is get rid of the `GIT_SSH` setting. One way to make sure the setting is *really* empty when using `git push` is if you run the command like this:

```
GIT_SSH= git push origin master
```

Comment: Correct!

This morning I woke up with an epiphany; remembering that the error actually came from putty, I reinstalled Git Bash this time configured with openssh instead of turtoise/putty plink etc. and it worked at once. The thing is, I had pageagent running and had the .ssh key imported there and still it wouldn't work. Took me all evening the day before... easy to lose track of time when dealing with ssh related things.

Comment: for those who are using PuTTY pageant with plink then the following command should be equivalent (assuming plink is in the PATH) `plink -ssh git@bitbucket.org`

Comment: When using `GIT_SSH= git push origin master` I get a fatal error. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

After all the other answers didnt do it for one of my collegues, I figured the following:

Since pushing to remotes like beanstalk works (https) and even ssh works using the git bash console, I figured it must have something to do with how SSH would be invoked, our remote was something like this:

```
user@server:/path/to/repo.git
```

So a simple `which ssh` gave us `/bin/ssh`

In the `.bashrc` profile we just added

```
export GIT_SSH=/bin/ssh.exe
```

and voila.

An easier solution would be to buy a mac! :)

Happy gitting

Comment: You sir - Are a genius!
I have been struggling for hours and your one-liner fixed it in a sec.
*Tips fedora*

Comment: you are so right, thanks a lot for this answer. I struggled for hours with it

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to connect to Bitbucket via SSH rather than through Git which is what the first error is telling you.   That you are not allowed to connect to Bitbucket in that manner.

When you set up your repo, if you are off of a existing one in Bitbucket all you would have needed to do is:

`git clone git@bitbucket.org:<UserName>/<Name of the Repo>.git`

You would get a message about accepting a key and you would have been all set.

Now if you have an already existing repo, you can add the remote yourself but you would add that to `.git/config`

You would add `url=git@bitbucket.org:<UserName>/<Name of the Repo>.git` to the section `[remote "origin"]`.

Comment: Yeah, I had that already, but still it wouldn't use SSH. Turns out it was because I installed GIT to use TurtoisePlink and puttygen.exe, instead of the ssh client provided with Git Bash.

Answer (score 1):

Try using cmd.exe. Git Bash seems to have issues with environment variables on my machine.

In CMD, `echo %GIT_SSH%` to see if it is set (PuTTY/Plink does that). If it is set, and you want to use openssh, clear it with `set GIT_SSH=`.

After doing that, I could push and pull using ssh in CMD with no issue, although Git Bash still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

For those facing this (or a similar problem), it was a completely different StackOverflow issue that hinted at my solution.

Turns out I had cloned from Bitbucket using the HTTPS address option instead of SSH.

[image]

And apparently if you run `git` while pointed at the HTTPS address, it doesn't give a toss if you've got a key or not.

- Go to your `.git/config`
- Check if your `remote "origin"` (or whatever) `url` is set to `https://...`
- If so, go to your Bitbucket repo, hit the Clone button, switch from HTTPS to SSH, and copy the address starting `git@bitbucket...`
- That's it.

(In your enthusiasm to test it out, don't forget to add your key to your agent again like I did.)