# Pushing to heroku gives PuTTY Fatal Error

Tags: git, heroku, putty

I am trying to push my local git repository to heroku using the following command (this is on a Windows 7 machine):

```
git push heroku master
```

However this brings up a popup showing the following error:

```
PuTTY Fatal Error
No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
```

I am wondering how PuTTY even comes into play here. Yes, I do have PuTTY installed on the machine, but the git command above should be simply reading my key from ~/.ssh directory where it is stored.

Comment: possible duplicate of [(git bash) push to bitbucket ignores SSH key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307154/git-bash-push-to-bitbucket-ignores-ssh-key)

Comment: Is it as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/7726603/6309 ?

Comment: These are indeed duplicates and answer my question. They were difficult to find though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [github: No supported authentication methods available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431314/github-no-supported-authentication-methods-available)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

is it possible you have the environment variable `GIT_SSH` set?

n.b.: if you have installed TortoiseGIT, you can answer that question with "yes".

So, if you have `GIT_SSH` set, you can fix your issue in several ways:

- add your key to plink / pageant
- set `GIT_SSH` to use your preffered (Open)SSH

For a lengthy explanation, read http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/version-control/git-on-windows.html